# Resize Image inside Grid to always fit available space

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a usercontrol containing two grids (top and bottom) and a Gridsplitter in between. The bottom grid will display an image for the selected item of the top grid (somewhat a details view).

I want to achieve the image to always fit the available space in the bottom grid, but the Stretch property of the image control doesn't work as i would expect it to. Can anyone help?

```
<UserControl x:Class="Picker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
    xmlns:dxprg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/propertygrid"
    xmlns:views="clr-
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="mainWindow">

  <UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/HintResources.xaml"/>
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <dx:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
  <functionPicker:StringToImageSourceConverter x:Key="StringToImageSourceConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>


<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height ="600" MinHeight="200"/>
  <RowDefinition Height ="15"/>
  <RowDefinition Height ="400" MinHeight="100"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width ="700"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<-- content top grid -->
</Grid>

<!--Horizontal Grid Splitter-->
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Height="11" Background="#FFDDDDDD" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
<Label Grid.Row="1" Content="...." FontSize="18" Height="42" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Gray"/>

<Grid  Grid.Row="2">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height ="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height ="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width ="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width ="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding DetailViewModels}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.Resources>         
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type provider:PreviewPageViewModel}">
        <Grid Background="White">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Source="{Binding PreviewPicturePath, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                 Stretch="Uniform" 
                 StretchDirection="DownOnly"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Visibility="{Binding PicturePathValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />             
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type provider:CodePageViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceCode}"></TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
  </TabControl>

  <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"  Margin="5" MinWidth="85" Height="25"  Content="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.CloseButton}" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsFuntionViewer, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: "*the Stretch property of the image control doesn't work as i would expect it to*" - what exactly is your expectation? `UniformToFill`perhaps? Or a total fill without respecting the image's aspect ratio, i.e. `Fill`?

Comment: @Clemens I want the image to fit the available size of the grid. After every resize (move of the gridsplitter or resize of the window hosting the control) the image should be completely visible on the one hand and theres no margin around the image on the other.

Comment: That does not seem to be possible while keeping the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: @Clemens I think it would be okay to have margins as small as possible to keep the image height/width ratio. Is that possible?

Comment: With `Stretch="Uniform"` that is already what you get. Except when you have set `StretchDirection="DownOnly"` by accident without knowing what its does.